# React map object containing array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an app which fetches the following JSON response:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Test 1",
      "parent": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "Test2",
      "parent": 5
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to map through the result, and display in an unordered list.

App.js:

```
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const searchDB = () => {
      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8443/subColumns/5/?key=fc257229-8f91-4920-b71f-885403114b35", {
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include'
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          (json) => {
            setIsLoaded(true);
            setItems(json);
          },
          (error) => {
            setIsLoaded(true);
            setError(error);
          }
        )
    }
    searchDB();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(items.result);
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {(Object.entries(items)).map(item => (
        <li key={items.id}>
          {item.id} - {item.name} - {item.parent}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

However, the current output shows the map is only running once and displays is as follows:

[image]

Comment: why don't you use `items.results.map(item => (...))` inside return ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need object entries, just do:

```
 <ul>
  {items.result.map(item => (
    <li key={items.id}>
      {item.id} - {item.name} - {item.parent}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach,

```
 items.result.map(({id, name, parent}) => 
       <li key={id}>
          {id} - {name} - {parent}
        </li>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using `map` for iteration is a good idea. `map` is used to iterate and make changes to the array based on its return value. If you simply want to iterate and display items use `forEach`

```
Because he interested in the return value in this case a an array of list items `map` is a better fit for this
<ul>
  {items.result.map(item => (
    <li key={items.id}>
      {item.id} - {item.name} - {item.parent}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: `Array.forEach` always [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) `undefined`.

Comment: That's right, that is why it's used for iteration purposes. Map is used when you want to create a new array based on the return values during iteration so it is not suitable for this case where he simply wants to iterate and display a list.

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: I just did and that article further emphasizes my point. You see in the article that the map method is used in the context of transforming lists and not just for iterating through a list but iterating through it and transforming it.

Comment: No actually it does not, i created [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-montalcini-wcm9m?file=/src/App.js) for you to see the difference between `forEach` and `map`.
the result of calling `forEach` is `undefined`.
the result of calling `map` is `Array` instance.
i hope this will help.

Comment: I am not saying that the result of calling forEach is something else. In this case he is not interested in the result of calling any of the methods that is why I say that to make the code expressive he should use forEach instead of map because when most developers see `map` they expect a result different from the original array which is not the case here. He simply wants to iterate through and display the list, he does not care about the result. Do you get my point now?

Comment: Did you take a look at the sandbox with your answer it does not render anything uncomment the snippet with `map` to see the results. Yes he is interested in the result with each iteration he is creating a `li` jsx element.

Comment: Great i get you now, I never thought he needed the result, should have read the question better thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create table body like -

```
render() {

let tableBody = this.items.map((item, index) => (
        <tr key={index} id="one">
               <td>item.id</td>
               <td>item.name</td>
               <td>item.parent</td>
        </tr>
      ));

//And in the render return -
 return (
                 <table>
                   <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Parent</th>
                        </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>{tableBody}</tbody>
               </table>

  )

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{(Object.result.entries(items)).map(item => (
        <li key={items.id}>
          {item.id} - {item.name} - {item.parent}
        </li>
      ))}
```